# Geoserver's CSS Styling: using feature id

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I'm using CSS to Style a layer in Geoserver, something like:

```
{
  mark: url('${getImageUrl(id)}');
   mark-mime: "image/png";
   mark-rotation: [rotationAngle];
}
```

getImageUrl is a custom Geotools function of mine. The problem is that Geoserver doesn't accept the id as a parameter, it gives the following exception:

```
ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid cql expression 'getImageUrl(id)'
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.ExpressionExtractor.splitCqlExpressions(ExpressionExtractor.java:122)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.ExpressionExtractor.extractCqlExpressions(ExpressionExtractor.java:162)
    at org.geotools.styling.StyleAttributeExtractor.visitCqlExpression(StyleAttributeExtractor.java:396)
    at org.geotools.styling.StyleAttributeExtractor.visit(StyleAttributeExtractor.java:410)
    at org.geotools.styling.ExternalGraphicImpl.accept(ExternalGraphicImpl.java:142)
    at org.geotools.styling.StyleAttributeExtractor.visit(StyleAttributeExtractor.java:346)
    at org.geotools.styling.GraphicImpl.accept(GraphicImpl.java:349)
    at org.geotools.styling.StyleAttributeExtractor.visit(StyleAttributeExtractor.java:232)
    at org.geotools.styling.PointSymbolizerImpl.accept(PointSymbolizerImpl.java:93)
    at org.geotools.styling.StyleAttributeExtractor.visit(StyleAttributeExtractor.java:96)
    at org.geotools.styling.RuleImpl.accept(RuleImpl.java:312)
    at org.geotools.styling.StyleAttributeExtractor.visit(StyleAttributeExtractor.java:114)
    at org.geotools.styling.FeatureTypeStyleImpl.accept(FeatureTypeStyleImpl.java:260)
    at org.geotools.styling.StyleAttributeExtractor.visit(StyleAttributeExtractor.java:77)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.checkStyle(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:1062)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:496)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1521)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:680)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:258)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLException: Encountered "id" at line 1, column 8.
Was expecting one of:
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "point" ...
    "linestring" ...
    "polygon" ...
    "multipoint" ...
    "multilinestring" ...
    "multipolygon" ...
    "geometrycollection" ...
    "envelope" ...
    "(" ...
    ")" ...
    "[" ...
    "-" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_LITERAL> ...
    <DATE> ...
    <DATE_TIME> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
     Parsing : getImageUrl(id).
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQLCompiler.compileExpression(ECQLCompiler.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.commons.CompilerUtil.parseExpression(CompilerUtil.java:175)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toExpression(ECQL.java:157)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toExpression(ECQL.java:136)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.ExpressionExtractor.splitCqlExpressions(ExpressionExtractor.java:119)
    ... 105 more
```

If I use any other int field as a parameter it works perfectly. What is the problem?

Comment: did you register your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is a keyword in CQL, you cannot use it like that. If you have a "id" attribute in your data, and it's visible in GeoServer layer page (e.g., it's not actually the primary key in a database, or you told the store to expose primary keys)  then you can try using `"id"` (notice the double quotes).

As a second note, filter functions do receive the entire feature, so if it's actually the feature identifier you're after, you can also write a function without any parameter and extract the id from the received feature (cast to SimpleFeature, then call getID()).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrea, I've tried SimpleFeature.getID() and it works perfectly.

Comment: However getImageUrl("id") doesn't work. it gives java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid cql expression 'getImageUrl(%22id%22)'

Comment: And when I use getImageUrl('id') (with a single quote) it gives no exceptions but the function sees a null id

Comment: Try getImageUrl('${"id"}')

Comment: It does not work. Please help me as I need it now. I tried the following:  mark: url('${getImageUrl('${"id"}')}');  but doesn't work.

Comment: It gives the following validation error: org.geotools.styling.css.CSSParseException: Invalid input '$', expected "px", 'm', "ft", '%', "deg", ECQLExpression, String, WhiteSpace, OptionalWhiteSpace, ',' or ')'